# How to completely delete a code pushed to git?

Tags: git

I did the initial commit to a branch in git . Now I need to completely delete that full code and push it from a new location . How to do that ?
Please help.

Comment: Why does the location from which you are pushing your code matter?  The whole point of Git is to let your development process be decentralized.

Comment: No,actually I want to push a different code actually. I want to completely remove the code what is in git right now .

Comment: Is creating a new repo and deleting the old one not an option?

Comment: can i do it without deleting the repo ?but just deleting the code ?

Comment: Deleting the code won't help, because all the files from your first commit are already a part of the history.  I vote for the new repo option.

Comment: can i go ahead by deleting all the files/folders separately in gitbash ??

Comment: Read the above comment again.

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual as one of the git values is to keep the historic differences but there is a solution.

You could use git filter-branch. This rewrite the history deleting even the old data:

```
    git filter-branch --force --index-filter \ 'git rm --cached --ignore-
   unmatch PATH_FILE_TO_DELETE' \
       --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
git reset —hard HEAD^
```

This command will delete all your changes , if you don’t want to lose them just avoid `—hard` and all changes will be there as you never commit them.

After that just make whatever commit you want, and finally push them force , for overriding remote changes.

```
git push -f <remote> <branch
```